# Wordpress - Can't get URL to be consistent with Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I'm officially clueless and in need of help or to be pointed in the right direction.
I've created a support videos section, the idea is:
List all categories of support video
Once you've selected a category, list all posts in said category.
Click on a post to view support video.

My problem is the URL is inconsistent. To view the list of categories you can go here:

```
http://www.byronware.com/how_to
```

That lists all the categories no problem using the archive-how_to.php file

When you select a category such as "Using System":

```
http://www.byronware.com/category/support-use
```

Notice the URL is now inconsistent, I want it to read

```
http://www.byronware.com/how_to/support-use
```

Currently i'm using the category-support-use.php to display all posts

and finally, when you go into a post:

```
http://www.byronware.com/how_to/use-the-celebrant-connection-2
```

I want the URL to read

```
http://www.byronware.com/how_to/support-use/use-the-celebrant-connection-2
```

I've been using Custom Post Type UI plugin to set up my Support Video Custom Post. Below is code I copied from CPT UI regarding creating the Support Vieo CPT:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_how_to' );
function cptui_register_my_cpts_how_to() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'Support Videos', '' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'Support Video', '' ),
        );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'Support Videos', '' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
                "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "how_to", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,

        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),      
        "taxonomies" => array( "category" ),
            );
    register_post_type( "how_to", $args );

// End of cptui_register_my_cpts_how_to()
}
```

For the Permalinks in Settings > Permalinks I'm using custom structure:

```
/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%
```

I don't understand CPT enough, the last thing I want to do is to tap into htaccess and start doing URL rewrites. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have a look at: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy